# Handing android app code to another developer: keystore management

Tags: android, security, export, keystore

I'm a freelance android developer. I have my own keystore file I use to sign the apk files I build for my customers. I give full source code to my customers along with the signed apk files. Most of the time, if not always, my customers authorize my google account to manage their Google Play developer console.
However I don't give my keystore to my customers («obviously!» I think).

One of my customers, which is a software house, has transferred the code for a published app to another software house, because the final client decided to change supplier. My customer transferred also the currently published app to the Google Play account of the new software house. The new software house now needs my keystore in order to update the app without changing its ID (or, at least, that's what they are asking for).

Now the problem is that my keystore is supposed to be kept private and secure and I'm not supposed to give it away to anyone. I could export the certificate I used to sign that app with something like:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias ...
```

but I don't know two things:

1) will the exported certificate suffice to the new software house in order to update the published app without changing its ID?

2) will the security of other apps I signed in the past with the same certificate still hold?

EDIT after [nasch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3307720/nasch) comment:

Using a different keystore for every client (or even for every app) may seem a reasonable workaround, but there must exist the real solution too.

Assuming I go for that workaround, when I create a new certificate (be it for a single client or a single app), keytool asks me for things like my name and my address. Whether I enter mine or the client's data, that data will be bound to that certificate forever, AFAIK. However I don't want it to be also bound to the app code forever, because my client can always decide to transfer that code to someone else, which is exactly what happened in my case. So, while using a different certificate for each app may technically solve some of the problems, it still leads to a situation where Software House 2 is signing its code with a certificate issued by Software House 1. Kinda weird.

Comment: I don't know the answers to your questions, but my general advice is to start using a different keystore for every client, that way there's no problem giving them the keystore if they need it.  Right now you have this weird situation where the code is theirs but the keystore that's needed to use it is sort of yours.